# Sum data per week SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to sum `alias` columns. I'm bad in English, so I will make a list about what I want to do.

1. There is an attendance in 2 weeks
2. If the employee have working more than `08:00 hours` in a week he will get `RO` (can multiple)

For now I'm able to show results with the extratime that employees have in a day.

Here is my query

```
select 
    a.Nip, b.FullName, c.attendancedate, c.inTime, c.OutTime,
    DATEPART(wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
    case 
       when DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime) <= InTime then '00:00' 
       else CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime - InTime), 108) 
    end AS total  
from 
    DinasHoDetail a 
left join 
    Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
left join 
    DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader
left join 
    attendance c on a.Nip = c.Nip and attendancedate between d.startdate and d.enddate
```

And here is the result

[image]

So can I add one more columns after total called with `ro`. The ro will contain a value from `total/8 hours group by week & Nip`

From week 36 and Nip 1502427 here is the example

```
02:00 + 02:00 + 02:00 / 8 hours
```

I'm sorry for my bad english.

I'm really want to create my table in `Fiddle`. Every time I run the query I always get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP BY and date functions to calculate RO for every Nip and weekday

```
select a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
   sum(case 
      when DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime) <=InTime then 0 
      else DATEDIFF(HOUR, InTime, OutTime) - 8
      end)/8 AS RO  
from DinasHoDetail a 
left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
left join DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader
left join attendance c on a.Nip =c.Nip and attendancedate 
between d.startdate and d.enddate
group by a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate)
```

Comment: now i find something new . That is `sum(case)` thanks.

Comment: can i just get the total ro ?

Comment: Yes, wrap above query into  `select sum(RO) from (...) q`

Comment: i have try that. i meant total for each nip

Comment: Then GROUP BY nip `select Nip,sum(RO) from (...) q group by Nip`

Answer (score 2):

Using a CTE, you can refer back to the query in multiple ways:

```
with BaseQuery as
(

select a.Nip,b.FullName,c.attendancedate,c.inTime,c.OutTime,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
case 
  when DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime) <=InTime then 0 
  else DATEDIFF(HOUR, InTime, OutTime) - 8
  end AS total  
from DinasHoDetail a 
left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
left join DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader
left join attendance c on a.Nip =c.Nip and attendancedate 
between d.startdate and d.enddate

)

select B1.Nip, B1.FullName, B1.AttendanceDate, B1.InTime, B1.OutTime, B1.Week, B1.Total, B2.RO
from BaseQuery B1
inner join 
(
select Nip, Week, sum(Total)/8 as RO
from BaseQuery
group by Nip, Week
) B2
on B2.Week = B1.Week
and B2.Nip = B1.Nip
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have try your answer , i get this error `Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator` i think in this part `select Nip, Week, sum(Total)/8 as RO`

Comment: Yep, I've just noticed you set the toal as a varchar... My bad